# IIS with Hamachi

Tags: django, iis, hamachi

I am trying to share a Django webapp with IIS and Hamachi, all is fine in debug mode and if I bind the site to my real LAN IP Address.
If i create an hamachi lan and put the hamachi IP address to binding the website I cannot reach the site anymore. I have already open the port TCP 90 (the one that i'm using now) on the firewall but nothing happen.
In the site log I have no errors.

What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to trace the connection via network monitor or wireshark?